# Memory access is not constant time

Tags: memory, time-complexity

There is a cute series of four blog posts arguing that memory access should not be considered constant time, but should instead incorporate a square root factor.  I cannot seem to find it now however.  Anyone got the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2v8dty/the_myth_of_ram_part_i_why_a_random_memory_read/

(*Literally the first result of a Google search*)

Leads to:

[The Myth of RAM, part I](http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2014/4/21/the-myth-of-ram-part-i)